# Powershell suppress all installer initiated reboots

Tags: powershell

The "proper" way for an installer to work is to allow a flag like -norestart, so a bunch of installs can be ganged, and even if all of them trigger a reboot, they can still all complete and I can trigger a reboot at the end. Works a treat. But Autodesk, being Autodesk, has come up with a new installer that no longer supports any kind of restart suppression. They prioritized eliminating unnecessary reboots, but removed the ability to suppress actual required reboots. The gist being any automated install of multiple Autodesk products can now fail because the first one could trigger an unsuppressed reboot. 
So, I am looking, as always with Autodesk, for a way around their, um, lack of good prioritization. Is there a mechanism in Powershell to block all installer initiated reboots? Or am I dependent on them getting their !@$@# together?

Comment: You can P/Invoke to `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate()`, which will prevent the system from rebooting outright, but will still pop up a UI detailing that a reboot is supposed to happen and asking the user what they want to do -- it isn't possible to suppress the shutdown silently. In theory you could run the installer under a user that doesn't have the privilege to shut down the system, but in practice installers will rely on (or check) that the user is in the Administrators group, which cannot (or rather should not) be denied this privilege.

Comment: In theory, you could duplicate the current user's token, call `AdjustTokenPrivileges()` to remove the `SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME` privilege and start the installer process under this token. Checks for whether the user is an administrator should still succeed, but the actual shutdown call will not since the privilege can't be enabled. I haven't tested this (it may not play nice with UAC) and the code for it is rather involved.

Comment: @jeroen-mostert Ah, wacky solutions, and it seems I would have issues then initiating my own reboot afterwards, which I need to do. I guess I just need to hope Autodesk pulls their head out soon. Which they have never done before, so not much hope there. Sigh. Though I might try using P/Invoke and see if I can automate the "user" interaction, and then reverse it when I am done. But hacky all around, and not ideal.